# Map value to a column if key isin 'value'

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

I have a dict

```
{'Spain':'34',
'Chile':'56',
'China':861'}
```

And a pandas dataframe:

```
| id | phone |
--------------
|  1 | 343123|
|  2 | 111111|
|  3 | 861231|
|  4 | 86911 |
|  5 | 56441 |
```

I want to map the dictionary to a new column the key if 'phone' startswith the value.

```
| id | phone | country |
------------------------
|  1 | 343123|   Spain |
|  2 | 111111|   None  |
|  3 | 861231|   China |
|  4 | 86911 |   None  |
|  5 | 56441 |   Chile |
```

**RELEVANT; DICTIONARY ORDER COULD BE REVERSED**

Comment: Why is 441 mapped to Chile?

Comment: @DaniMesejo My mistake, editing, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can pandas' apply -

```
def my_func(x, my_dict):
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        if x.startswith(v):
            return k
    return None

my_dict = {
    'Spain':'34',
    'Chile':'56',
    'China':'861'}

df['phone'].apply(lambda x: my_func(x, my_dict))
```

Since there is prefixes may overlap, I suggest using an ordered data structure, e.g list, see below. The code will require slight modification.

```
prefixes = [('Spain', '34'), ('Chile', '56'), ('China', '861')]
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an edit where the dictionary could be inverted but I your answer works!

Comment: I dont understand your last edit with using a list, why the Cihna tuple is split by ":" instead of  ","? And how would that work?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the China example. Thanks for letting me know. The function would change to `def my_func(x, prefixes): for k, v in prefixes: ....` (all the rest is the same).

Comment: Thanks again! Will accept your answer as valid but still I don't see what problems does it solve with the overlap prefixing?

Comment: Assume you have {"Spain": "1234", "US": "123"} and you want to make sure that every. time the number starts with "1234" you return "Spain" and not "US" you have to define some order on the dictionary. One way to solve it is to use an ordered data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
lookup = {'Spain': '34',
          'Chile': '56',
          'China': '861'}

reverse = { v: k  for k, v in lookup.items()}

df['country'] = df['phone'].astype(str)\
    .str.extract(fr'^({"|".join(reverse.keys())})')\
    .squeeze().map(reverse)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   id   phone country
0   1  343123   Spain
1   2  111111     NaN
2   3  861231   China
3   4   86911     NaN
4   5   56441   Chile
```

Comment: Thanks! Really nice didn't know about the squeeze function